# Django URLConf: page not found error

Tags: python, django, url, django-views

I am getting the error when resolving url http://127.0.0.1:8000/userprofile/auth. Below is my urls.py file for the userprofile app:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from userprofile import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.login),
    url(r'^auth/$' , views.auth_view),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout),
    url(r'/loggedin/$', views.loggedin),
    url(r'/invalid/$', views.invalid_login),
)
```

The main urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from userprofile import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^userprofile/', include('userprofile.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Here's a [link](http://tinypic.com/r/33f6sxy/8) to the screenshot of browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `/` slash to the `action` attribute of your `<form>`:

```
<form action="/userprofile/auth/" method="POST">
```

Or, as the better solution, name the url:

```
url(r'^auth/$' , views.auth_view, name='auth_view'),
```

and use the `{% url %}` tag in the template:

```
<form action="{% url 'auth_view' %}" method="POST">
```